# mimicking jQuery plugins with plain javascript or coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Without using jQuery, I'd like to know how to mimik a jQuery plugin

For example, maybe $('div.x').plugin() attaches an onclick to divs, and increments and displays an internal value.

Where does jQuery actually store the object with the internal variable?

Does an object get explicitly created somewhere and associated with each node?

I get lost trying to explain to myself why there is no explicit object creation in the main application listing.... must happen within the plugin somehow?

(PS: I am less concerned with the query engine side... just the plugin side :)

thanks

Answer (score 6):

Normally you define a function like `plugin()` by writing

```
$.fn.plugin = ...
```

As discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-dev/ikxND4njKLs), `$.fn` is actually just a shortcut for `jQuery.prototype`. When you attach a method to a constructor's prototype, JavaScript automatically attaches it to all instances created from that constructor with the `new` keyword, which jQuery does internally when you write something like `$('li')`. See http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/.

So here's a simple example of creating a library called `kQuery` in CoffeeScript that allows you to 1) create named instances and 2) add plugins:

```
instances = {}
kQuery = (name) ->
K = (name) ->
  return instances[name] if instances[name]
  instances[name] = new kQuery name
K.fn = kQuery.prototype
```

That's it! Now if someone were to write

```
K.fn.plugin = -> console.log 'foo'
K('whatev').plugin()
```

they'd see `foo` on their console. Note that the reason for the separate `kQuery` and `K` functions is that if you called `new K` from within the `K` function, you'd get an infinite loop (which would resolve to an error).